# Beam SDK harness still trying to launch docker when I set environment_type to be `PROCESS`

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-beam

According to the [beam harness documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runtime/sdk-harness-config/):

> PROCESS: User code is executed by processes that are automatically started by the runner on each worker node.

```
args = [
            "--runner=portableRunner",
            "--streaming",
            "--sdk_worker_parallelism=2",
            "--environment_type=PROCESS",
            "--environment_config={\"command\": \"/opt/apache/beam/boot\"}",
        ]
```

```
consumer_config = {
            "security.protocol": "SASL_SSL",
            "sasl.mechanism": "AWS_MSK_IAM",
            "sasl.jaas.config": "software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule required;",
            "sasl.client.callback.handler.class": "software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler",
            "bootstrap.servers": bootstrap_servers,
        }
with beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions(args)) as p:
        data = p | "Reading messages from Kafka" >> ReadFromKafka(
           consumer_config=consumer_config,
           topics=topics,
           with_metadata=True
         )
         data | 'Writing to stdout' >> beam.Map(logging.info)
```

But when I run the code (deployed to k8s using [flinkk8soperator](https://github.com/lyft/flinkk8soperator)), it is complaining:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "docker": error=2, No such file or directory
```

Wondering if I misunderstand anything? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After couple digging, I finally make the cross language work without using DinD or DooD. Here's the steps:

1. Ensure both job and task manager mount a shared volume for artifact staging. (This is required, otherwise the task manager will complained unable to find the submitted jar)
2. Ensure your docker image can run both java and python beam code, here's what I did:

```
# python SDK 
COPY --from=apache/beam_python3.7_sdk:2.41.0 /opt/apache/beam/ /opt/apache/beam/

# java SDK
COPY --from=apache/beam_java8_sdk:2.41.0 /opt/apache/beam/ /opt/apache/beam_java/
```

3. In the job, you'll need to start the expansion service with extra args, for example the KafkaIo:

```
from apache_beam.io.kafka import ReadFromKafka, default_io_expansion_service
ReadFromKafka(
                consumer_config=consumer_config,
                topics=[topic],
                with_metadata=False,
                expansion_service=default_io_expansion_service(
                    append_args=[
                        '--defaultEnvironmentType=PROCESS',
                        "--defaultEnvironmentConfig={\"command\":\"/opt/apache/beam_java/boot\"}",
                    ]
                )
```

Comment: how did you configured a shared volume for artifact staging? I'm using the [Flink-k8s-operator](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-kubernetes-operator-docs-main/docs/concepts/architecture/) but still get an error that the task manager cannot find the files in /tmp/beam-artifact-staging/...

Comment: You'll need to mount a shared volume for the task manager and job manager for staging artifact. I am using [lyft/flinkk8soperator](https://github.com/lyft/flinkk8soperator) but I think the config should be similar. 
```
volumes:
  - name: flink-staging
     persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: flink-staging
```
and 
```
volumeMounts:
- mountPath: /tmp/beam-artifact-staging
   name: flink-staging
```
I actually have tried using s3, but couldn't figured out a way to pass in the s3 path. This is what I come up with so far that seems work for us.

Answer (score 0):

You portable execution relies on xLang support that requires starting a Java SDK with docker. Your cluster doesn't have docker installed.

Comment: According to the documentation, docker is required only if I configured the `--environment_type=DOCKER` (this is also the default configuration).  But given that I specified to use `PROCESS` instead, it supposed not try to launch with docker at all ?

Comment: It only defines where the user code should be executed. Your flink job server itself still runs in  a docker container.

Comment: But I am in kuberentes, and due to the security concern, I cannot use DinD approach. I've also tried setting environment variable to external but the harness is still trying to start a docker container. How can I avoid this behavior?  Thanks!

Comment: If possible, you can also do DooD by binding your host's docker socket through `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`. It's a different approach from DinD. If it's also not applicable, you can resort to using Beam Java SDK so that you don't need to use portability and xLang.